# can i update my local text file on iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a  text file so can i update this text file from web ???
lets say i have

```
   1. NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];  
   2. NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
   3. if (myData) {  
   4.     // do something useful  
   5. }
```

right now Myfile.text is having 10 data so how to insert 10 more to this data??

plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files stored inside your app bundle will not be writable.

You will have to make a copy of the file and store it in the Documents or Library folder before you will be able to edit it.